# Automate fast user switching in windows through a script

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, fast-user-switching

To switch to another user in windows you have to lock (Win+L), then switch, then login with the other user's credentials.

A little quicker way is through Task manager's Users tab where you right click the logged in user and "Connect". You still have to enter the credentials but at least you can skip the lock screen, but you have to open up the taskbar and navigate to the Users tab...

[image]

Is there a way to automate this through a script in which I can store the credentials making the whole procedure just a single click task?

Comment: Just as FYI in case you didn't already know, you can press `Esc`+`Shift`+`Ctrl` to get Task Manager up quickly to potentially help make that part quicker to until you find a full answer if this is possible, I don't have Windows 10 available to test otherwise. But building something with AutoIT or scripts to emulate the keyboard strokes may be able to automate it further with less manual clicks. This would assume that other account is already signed on though but disconnected which may not always be the case in the event you reboot, etc. so there may be other factors to consider as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You Can Create a Windows Shortcut to

   ```
   %systemroot%\system32\tsdiscon.exe
   ```

   If you are switching to an account that’s already logged in, you can creat a batch with the command **tscon** instead with the proper syntax. [Read More about it here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321703)
2. You can Use [Fast User
   Switch](http://www.myportablesoftware.com/fastuserswitch.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Direct User Switching Task (DUST)](http://www.waybeyonduk.com/DUST/) for years.

However, since using Win10 I have just been using the ability to my domain admin account using the fingerprint reader on my ThinkPad laptop and Win10's ability to use it to do that (part of Windows Hello, I think).